# Reference for Arakelov's theorem: $K^2_f=0$ iff $f$ is locally trivial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces, fibration

Let $f:X\longrightarrow B$ be a family of curves, **with $f$ relatively minimal**, over a fixed curve $B$ ($B$ is projective, irreducible and smooth). The fibration $f$ is said locally trivial if all fibers are smooth and isomorphic, and moreover the number $K^2_f$ is defined as 
$$K^2_f=K^2_X-8(g-1)(g(B)-1)$$
where $g$ is the genus of a fiber.

> **Edit:** $g\ge2$

I'd like to have a reference for the proof of the following theorem:

> $K^2_f=0$ **if and only if** $f$ is locally trivial.

All authors attribute this theorem to Arakelov and cite the article "S.Ju. Arakelov - family of algberaic curves with fixed degeneracy". In this article I can't find the above theorem! Can you suggest me an alternative reference?

Comment: You must assume $g\geq 2$, otherwise this is false. Then this Theorem 2' in "exposé no. 3" by Szpiro, Asterisque 86.

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately this article is not free on the web.

Comment: $K_{f}^2 = \omega_{X/B}^2$, the self-intersection of the relative dualizing sheaf considered in Arakelov's paper. If $X/B$ is locally trivial, it is obvious that $\omega_{X/B}^2 = 0$, for then $\omega_{X/B}$ is a pull-back after a base change. Otherwise, Arakelov proves in Proposition 3.2 that $\omega_{X/B}$ is an amples sheaf: this is his famous rigidity theorem. Hence, $\omega_{X/B}^2 > 0$ when $f$ is not locally trivial.

Comment: Please don't write $K^2=\omega^2$!! One of them is a *divisor*, the other is a *sheaf*. There is a reason these notions are distinguished. $\omega^2$ is the line bundle corresponding to the divisor $2K$ and not the number $K^2$. Of course, what you have in mind is different, but then why not write down what you have in mind? It's not that hard. You could have written for instance that $K^2=c_1(\omega)^2$...

Comment: @SándorKovács: I meant of course the self-intersection $(\omega_{X/B},\omega_{X/B})$ of the line bundle $\omega_{X/B}$ on $X$, whereas $K_f^2$ was the quantity defined by the OP. (It is just a number, that turns out to be equal to the self-intersection. $K_f$ in the question is not a divisor, it is just a notation.) But you are right, I should better write $c_1(\omega_{X/B})^2$ for this (although I would have written $\omega_{X/B}^{\otimes 2}$ if I meant the other notion. I would never write $L^n$ for the tensor powers of a line bundle; these for me are intersection numbers).

Comment: @Vesselin: of course you did. I didn't think you meant the tensor power, but no one can know what you *would have written* if you meant something else than what you *have actually written*! And just to be a bit nitpicking, there is no such thing as the self-intersection of a line bundle. That's my point. Cycles have self-intersections and line bundles have associated divisors which are cycles. (OK, you *could* define self-intersection of a line bundle as the self-intersection of the associated divisor, but that's besides the point)...

Comment: (con't-ed) This may seem a trivial point to you now, but it can lead to disaster if you don't keep your notions in order. As an exercise compare the push forwards $f_*K_f$ and $f_*\omega_{X/B}$...

Comment: @SándorKovács: OK, I see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are saying is not entirely correct.

1. That equation for $K_f^2$ is not a **definition**. It's a consequence of the definition of $K_f$ as $K_X-f^*K_B$: If $F$ denotes a fiber of $f$, then since $K_X\cdot F=\deg K_F = 2g-2$, 
   $$
   K_f^2 = K_X^2 - 2 K_X\cdot f^*K_B = K_X^2 - 2 K_X\cdot (2g(b)-2) F = K_X^2 - 2(2g-2)(2g(B)-2).
   $$
2. The statement you are looking for is not exactly like that. $K_f^2=0$ is not equivalent to $f$ being locally trivial, but being generically locally trivial. That is, for instance it might have some singular fibers, but the smooth fibers are isomorphic. The right word actually is *isotrivial*, which is defined as two general fibers being isomorphic.

With that said, *Vesselin* already gave you the correct reference, but at the same time there is a whole lot of newer results that deal with these kind of questions.

The modern approach is that first of all regardless of any assumption on isotriviality, the sheaf $f_*\mathscr O_X(mK_{f})$ is semipositive for large and divisible enough $m$. Then using the fact that the fibers are canonically polarized varieties (that's the real reason you need $g\geq 2$), the natural map 
$$f^*f_*\mathscr O_X(mK_{f})\to \mathscr O_X(mK_{f})$$ is generically surjective, so with a bit of work you can prove that $K_f$ is nef and then $K_f^2\geq 0$ always and then $K_f^2> 0$ if and only if $K_f=K_{X/B}$ is big. That last condition follows from 3.2 in Arakelov's paper as *Vesselin* already mentioned. (By the way, that result is for a *stable* model of $f$ which is not necessarily smooth, but everything works out at the end).

The advantage of this approach is that this works in higher dimensions as well.

Comment: I only add that a stable isotrivial fibration of genus $g\ge 2$ is locally trivial. Therefore in the stable case my statement should be correct.